# The required column 'id' was not present in the results of a `FromSql` operation

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have this entity class:

```
public class PoDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to run a query on it:

```
public IActionResult Data()
    {           
        var result = _context.PoDetail
            .FromSqlRaw("select count(ProductId) as count, ProductId from dbo.PoDetail group by ProductId").ToList();
        return Json(result);         
    }
```

It works fine when I run in query console.
But on the browser I am getting this error:

> The required column 'id' was not present in the results of a `FromSql` operation

But if I include the id column in query. I won't get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new class to hold the desired result:

```
public class PoSummary
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Add it to your DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PoSummary>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

And then:

```
public IActionResult Data()
    {           
        var result = _context.PoSummary
            .FromSqlRaw("select count(ProductId) as count, ProductId from dbo.PoDetail group by ProductId").ToList();
        return Json(result);         
    }
```

Comment: This will create a new table in database ?

Comment: No, it will not

Answer (score 0):

I've used it this way before.

```
select ProductId , count(*) as TotalId from dbo.PoDetail group by ProductId
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For such simple query, you do not need SQL:

```cs
public IActionResult Data()
{           
    var result = _context.PoDetail
        .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId)
        .Select(g => new 
        {
            count = g.Count()
            ProductId = g.Key
        })
        .ToList();
    return Json(result);         
}
```

Comment: I know about this. I just wanted to do it with SQL